# Deleting all nodes inside a linked list

Tags: c++, c++11

I've created this function, and I'm wanting to delete all of the nodes inside of the linked list. However, it doesn't seem to be working and only deletes the first node (?).

```
void deleteList(Node* &pTemp) {
    Node *pCurrent = pTemp;
    Node* next = NULL;

    while(pCurrent != NULL) {
        next = pCurrent -> nextNode;
        free(pCurrent);
        pCurrent = next;
    }
}
```

What can I do to make this delete every single node, but still have an empty list?

Comment: 1. Please provide a minimal working example. 2. It doesn't look like you need to declare, nor initialize, `next` outside of your while loop. 3. In C++, we use `nullptr` for null pointers, and allocate/free with the `new` and `delete` operators.

Comment: You never modify `pTemp`, leaving the caller with a dangling pointer and undefined behaviour when dereferencing it.

Comment: Add `pTemp = NULL;` after the loop is finished (or, at least, after `pTemp` is assigned to `pCurrent`).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Please see [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-function-to-delete-a-linked-list/):

```
void deleteList(Node** head_ref)
{
 
    /* deref head_ref to get the real head */
    Node* current = *head_ref;
    Node* next = NULL;
 
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        next = current->next;
        free(current);
        current = next;
    }
 
    /* deref head_ref to affect the real head back
        in the caller. */
    *head_ref = NULL;
}
```